# converting pandas dataframe to contain a list

Tags: python, pandas

```
      state      Year  Month  count
0       alabama  2017.0   10.0     31
1       alabama  2017.0   11.0     30
2       alabama  2017.0   12.0     31
3       alabama  2018.0    1.0     31
4       alabama  2018.0    2.0     28
5       alabama  2018.0    3.0     31
6       alabama  2018.0    4.0     30
7       alabama  2018.0    5.0     31
8       alabama  2018.0    6.0     30
9       alabama  2018.0    7.0     14
10     arkansas  2017.0   10.0     31
11     arkansas  2017.0   11.0     30
12     arkansas  2017.0   12.0     31
```

Can I convert dataframe above to:

```
                                                            Month
state                                                        
alabama         [10.0, 11.0, 12.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0]
arkansas        [10.0, 11.0, 12.0]
```

I tried using unstack but that does not work

Comment: Its a dupe, use df.groupby('state').Month.apply(list)

Comment: Unstack isn't going to work because this isn't a MultiIndex.