# converting pandas dataframe to contain a dictionary or list of lists

Tags: python, pandas

```
      state      Year  Month  count
0       alabama  2017.0   10.0     31
1       alabama  2017.0   11.0     30
2       alabama  2017.0   12.0     31
3       alabama  2018.0    1.0     31
4       alabama  2018.0    2.0     28
5       alabama  2018.0    3.0     31
6       alabama  2018.0    4.0     30
7       alabama  2018.0    5.0     31
8       alabama  2018.0    6.0     30
9       alabama  2018.0    7.0     14
10     arkansas  2017.0   10.0     31
11     arkansas  2017.0   11.0     30
12     arkansas  2017.0   12.0     31
```

Can I convert dataframe above to:

```
                                                            Month
state                                                        
alabama         {2017:10.0, 2017:11.0, 2017:12.0, 2018:1.0, 2018:2.0, 2018:3.0, 2018:4.0, 2018:5.0, 2018:6.0, 2018:7.0}
arkansas        {2017:10.0, 2017:11.0, 2017:12.0}
```

related to [converting pandas dataframe to contain a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47641184/converting-pandas-dataframe-to-contain-a-list)

based on @Vaishali's comment below, since dictionary cannot contain duplicate keys, this should be ok too:

```
                                                            Month
state                                                        
alabama         [[2017,10.0], [2017,11.0], [2017,12.0], [2018,1.0], [2018,2.0], [2018,3.0], [2018,4.0], [2018,5.0], [2018,6.0], 2[018,7.0]]
arkansas        [[2017,10.0], [2017,11.0], [2017,12.0]]
```

Comment: what happens to the count column?

Comment: Did you look at the NumPy level answer from the linked duplicate on your other question? With a bit of effort, adapting it for your dicts (with proper keys) should not be hard. Have you tried anything?

Comment: @MattR, you can ignore the count column

Comment: @user308827, I'd remove it from the question then. May be misleading for others too

Comment: You can not create a dictionary with duplicate keys

Comment: @MattR Not really? There are plenty of Pandas operations where you ignore certain columns (and using a subset of columns is part of the specification).

Comment: There is no way for creating duplicate keys for dict

Comment: You can at best get alabama     {2017.0: 12.0, 2018.0: 7.0} and arkansas                 {2017.0: 12.0}

Comment: @user308827, I might be splitting hairs here. that's why I used "may" but when I think [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) it's a luxury to have only what you need.

Comment: As @Vaishali has already said it contradicts the nature of dictionary - you can't have duplicated keys in a dictionary

Comment: thanks @Vaishali, you have a valid point. I have modified question to get list of lists instead of dictionary

Comment: @MattR, I will point this out in the question. I do not want to remove `count` just in case proposed soln does not work with `count` included

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try

```
df.groupby('state').apply(lambda x: list(zip(x['Year'], x['Month'])))


state
alabama     [(2017.0, 10.0), (2017.0, 11.0), (2017.0, 12.0...
arkansas     [(2017.0, 10.0), (2017.0, 11.0), (2017.0, 12.0)]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
In [73]: (df.groupby('state')['Year','Month']
            .apply(lambda x: x.values.tolist())
            .to_frame('Month')
            .reset_index())
Out[73]:
      state                                              Month
0   alabama  [[2017.0, 10.0], [2017.0, 11.0], [2017.0, 12.0...
1  arkansas   [[2017.0, 10.0], [2017.0, 11.0], [2017.0, 12.0]]
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess this will work.

```
d={}
for index, row in df.iterrows():
  if(d.get(row['state'],0)==0):
    d[row['state']=[].append(str(row['year'])+" : "+ str(row['month']))
  else:
    d[row['state']] = d[row['state']].append(str(row['year'])+" : "+ str(row['month']))
```

This will have it like

```
arkansas        ["2017 : 10.0", "2017 : 11.0", "2017 : 12.0"]
```

Answer (score 1):

Or also

```
df.groupby('state').apply(lambda x:x[['Year','Month']].values)

state
alabama     [[2017.0, 10.0], [2017.0, 11.0], [2017.0, 12.0...
arkansas     [[2017.0, 10.0], [2017.0, 11.0], [2017.0, 12.0]]
```